# User cannot edit her own profile in rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have built one application using ruby on rails. Here an user can have multiple roles. In ability.rb I have put the following two lines for managing User model:

```
if user.role? :x
  can :manage, User
  cannot :destroy, User
```

But the problem I am facing now is that, whenever an user with role x is logging in my application she can do operations except destroy on every other users of the application which is as expected according to ability.rb. But she cannot edit her own profile, it keeps saying that **The user can not edit that profile**. I have no idea how to fix that.

Comment: Please include the rest of your ability.rb

Comment: Rest of the ability does not matter, I think because the these are the only two lines involving user model.

Comment: Assuming you have current_user set, which is a requirement of CanCan, you can try the following `can :manage, User do |user|
  user == current_user
end`

Comment: can :manage, User user.id: current_user.id I hope your user model is not polymorphic